# Cannot type into input in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

On my website, inputs for login are generated through jQuery. In chrome it work well, you can simple click on the input, type text, etc... In firefox, you need to use tab key and then you can type your text. Simple click does nothing. I also find out, that this happens only for JS generated inputs, when inputs are manually added through HTML, you can type text like it should. Is there any trick for firefox? I know I can use jQuery "hack" like that:

```
$('input').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).focus();
});
```

But I think it's lame. Why JS generated inputs doesn't work in FF?